# JUnit Eclipse View

Tags: junit, junit4

I am running Junit tests using Eclipse Luna. I have implemented `@Test` method. I loop within the `@Test` method for multiple records and use `Assert.assertEquals` for Non-XML messages and `XMLAssert.assertXMLEqual` for XML messages.

The problem is, when I run the Junit with single or multiple test cases, I do not get the proper result in the Junit View. It always shows "`Runs: 1/1`" and does not show the correct count of runs. Even the failures and success are not shown correctly. Am I missing something here?

Comment: check if you have too many run time configurations, if so delete them all and run the junit again & add screenshot to get more clarity on your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a single `@Test` method, there is only one thing running, so the `Runs: 1/1` is correct. If you want to have more show up, make each assertion in its own test.